# How to understand this perl multi-line writing command

Tags: perl

I am trying to understand the perl commands below:

```
$my = << EOU;

This is an example.

Example too.

EOU
```

What is the name of this way? Could somebody can explain more about this "multi-line writing" command?

Comment: [Here documents, or how to create multi-line strings in Perl](http://perlmaven.com/here-documents)

Comment: This is what I want! Thank you!

Comment: @Сухой27, there is an error "space" between "<<" and "EOU". The correct vision is: $my = <<EOU;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially the syntax is allowing you to put anything unique as a marker so that it won't conflict with your contents.  You can do this:

```
$my = <<ABCDEFG;
This is an example.
Example too.

BLAH
ABCDEFG
```

Everything between "This.." and "BLAH" will be assigned to the variable. Note that you shouldn't have a space after the << symbols otherwise you will get a syntax error.  It helps avoid adding CR characters, or append (.) everywhere, and useful when passing data into another application (eg. ftp session).  [Here Documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) is the correct term for this.

Answer (score 0):

Everything between <<EOU and EOU is a multi-line, non-escapable, string.  It's nothing fancy, think of them as start and end quote marks with nothing inside requiring escapes to be literally what you typed...

Comment: non-escapable?  You mean non-interpolating?  That would only be the cause if the heredoc label was enclosed in single quotes.  By default it's double-quoted.